# Generate JSON Response from PHP

Tags: php, json

Im new to PHP and. im making mobile app and also building web service for it.
from mobile im sending 2 parameters as a POST and want to retrieve data as a JSON data.

below is my PHP code.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'connection.php';
$response = array();

$location = $_POST['location'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


        $query = "SELECT * FROM Feeds WHERE location='".$location."' AND country = '".$country."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
      {

          $response["Result"] = 1;
          $response["message"] = "Here Data";

      }else{
          $response["Result"] = 0;
          $response["message"] = "No Data";

      }



echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
```

when i test current response is like below.

```
{"Result":1,"message":"Here Data"}
```

but i want to retrieve result data as well along with above response message. like below

```
{
    "Result": 1,
    "Message": "Here Data",
    "Feeds": [
        {
            "userid": "2",
            "name": "Demo",
            "address": "Demo"
        },
         {
            "userid": "2",
            "name": "Demo",
            "address": "Demo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you didn't get the result of your query

Comment: @DiegoMariani how can i do that. get result and generate response

Comment: add this: `$response["Feeds"] = mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $result);`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i got error like below `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in <b>/home/u832689343/public_html/ws/demo.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
{"Result":1,"message":"Here Data","Feeds":null}`

Comment: Remove the $conn then, my bad sorry  `$response["Feeds"] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: One thing..  Escape your inputs! Your code is wide open to SQL-injections.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson any guide i can look for avoid SQL-injections? i have no idea about it

Comment: Look up mysqli and prepared statements. Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php - If you want to know more about SQL-injections, just Google "php mysql sql inejctions" and you will find a lot of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to itterate over the result from the SQL query too.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'connection.php';
$response = array();

$location = $_POST['location'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


    $query = "SELECT * FROM Feeds WHERE location='".$location."' AND country = '".$country."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
  {

      $response["Result"] = 1;
      $response["message"] = "Here Data";
      while($feed = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC){
          $response['Feeds'][] = $feed;
      }

  }else{
      $response["Result"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "No Data";

  }



echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: And if your PHP-version is compiled with mysqlnd, then you can use: `$response['Feed'] = mysqli_fetch_all($result);` instead of the `while`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution. You should also push your query result in your `$response` array. Used the [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) function. [`header('Content-Type: application/json')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be called before any actual output is sent, I suggest you to put in the end of your script, to avoid possible mistakes

```
include 'connection.php';
$response = array();

$location = $_POST['location'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM Feeds WHERE location='".$location."' AND country = '".$country."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {

    $response["feeds"] = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $response["feeds"][] = $row;
    }

    $response["Result"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Here Data";

} else {
    $response["Result"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Data";
}

$conn->close();


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```